# Let keystrokes pass through flash?

Tags: html, flash

On a page i have a flash file. I click it once to start something and i typically leave the page. When i get back i may want to press ctrl tab or w however it doesnt work because the flash file is catching the events. How do i make events pass through the flash so that the file acts like a normal button and will continue to allow me to press ctrl w, tab or any other keystroke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn about ExternalInterface and use it to catch keystroke events and echo them to the page. Or just use it to set the focus to the page, call something like document.body.focus().

Comment: +1. This sounds like a flash interface/function? unfortunately i don't have the source but i'll see if i could do something about that.