# Is it possible to add code to a compiled SWF?

Tags: flash

[I asked this question about passing keystrokes to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413852/let-keystrokes-pass-through-flash). Is there a simple way for me to add this to an already compiled swf?

Answer (score 2):

Not simple, no. SWFs are a compiled format, so the only realistic way to add in content is to decompile/edit/recompile, using a third-party decompiler of some sort. (In theory you could inject compiled code directly into the SWF, but you'd need to understand the file format pretty well to know whether you needed to redo checksums and so on.)

Answer (score -1):

if the compiled swf's security allows it, you can probably load that swf into another swf and have the parent swf catch all the keystrokes.